# wpf binding: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Tags: wpf, multithreading

I am getting this error after raising NotifyPropertyChange event from a view model property.

I added (as a test) an UI Dispatcher.Invoke call on the setter which seems to have fixed the problem temporarily.

```
   public FeedTrackingSummary SelectedFeedTracking {
        get { return _selectedFeedTracking; }
        set { 
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() => {
                _selectedFeedTracking = value; Notify("SelectedFeedTracking");
            }));
        }
    }
```

SelectedFeedTracking below is set by choosing a dropdown value which is bound to this property:

```
<ComboBox... SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFeedTracking}"  />
```

the error happens after selecting a drop-down value. There is no other code setting this property. I guess my viewmodel is used in a background thread at the time this happens?

*UPDATE*

i tried removing the call to INotifyPropertyChanged, and set a totally different property, and the error still persists. so i guess this has to do with the accessibility of the whole viewmodel ?

```
        set { 
            SelectedCalc = -1;
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Some MVVM Frameworks (such as Caliburn.Micro, for example) have a base `NotifyPropertyChanged` class which automatically marshals property change notifications (by raising the `PropertyChanged` event) to the so-called "UI Thread".

So, instead of having to `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke`(...) on every property setter, put that code in your `Notify()` method. Thus making sure every time you notify property changes in the ViewModel you do so in the UI thread.